# Is it useful to create a Facebook page for a website?

Tags: facebook, marketing

I'm aware Facebook pages can be used as a communication and marketing channel for a website. Is there value in creating a Facebook page for a noncommercial website that is moderately trafficked?

The idea behind this is to create additional informational/marketing channels for some websites I run.

Comment: I'm testing one too now. I will see and let you know. I took me couple of hours to set it up with a nice image and to udnerstand all the FB useless UI. So now I want to see if it has been worth the effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facebook is the fastest growing social network right now, and pretty much every major corporation has a facebook page, regardless of their business or whether they're B2C or B2B. So I don't think there's any problem with having a facebook page in terms of looking childish or unprofessional.

However, I wouldn't create a facebook page just to jump on the social media bandwagon. A facebook page requires regular updates to be effective. Otherwise, you may accrue some fans, but it won't actually do anything for you. The same goes for Twitter or any other social media site.

Also, don't treat social media as free adspace. People don't subscribe to a facebook page or follow a Twitter account just so they can get ads. SMM is about engaging customers in conversation to find out what your customers want, and also strengthen your brand by providing richer interaction.

A company that posts exclusive content, responds to fan comments, and gives free stuff on their facebook page will, not only gain lots more fans, but their brand will be a stronger presence in the minds of consumers than a company that just spams their facebook page fans or uses their facebook page as a billboard.

Comment: "A facebook page requires regular updates to be effective" Yes. I see this all too often, management types are keen to be seen using the latest technologies to show that they are "with it", so they will set it up, make a big song and dance about it to get the brownie points then abandon it after 6 weeks rendering it a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

I honestly haven't noticed any improvement with the implementation of a facebook page for my website. With that being said I know hat there are people that has had a great deal of success with a Facebook page. Keeping this in mind I'd say that it's probably worth a try. If worse came to worse it wouldn't make a huge difference, but it could very well help.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your market or prospective audience.  One of the groups I work with are students age 14 to 19.  They receive significantly more hits on their [Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/team781), than their [website](http://www.team781.com/2010/index.php).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your business.  If its a web business then the answer is yes, because of the added exposure.  If you are a commercial real estate firm, and do your business through traditional channels then having a facebook page may seem immature or childish.